# Query optimization for convert VARBINARY to VARCHAR and charindex on it

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, varbinary

I have a repository table which has around 18.7 million rows  and every month around 500 thousand to 100 thousand rows are added. The table structure is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table](
    [id] [bigint] NULL,
    [a_timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventId] [bigint] NULL,
    [userId] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [customerid] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [messageType] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [message] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have written the following query to get various counts for each month. The query takes around 10 minutes to execute now. I need help to optimize this query and if possible to bring the time to a couple of mins.

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,a_timestamp), 0) AS MonthYear, 
       COUNT(*) AS [Count], 
       COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) AS [Unique Customers], 
       COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS  [Unique Users]
FROM [my_table]
WHERE messageType = 'Outbound'
AND userId NOT IN ('master', 'admin')
AND CHARINDEX('Retrieve Document',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[message])) > 1
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,a_timestamp), 0) 
ORDER BY MonthYear
```

I think the key reasons for the long execution time are as follows

- `CHARINDEX('Retrieve Document',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[message])) > 1` converting from VARBINARY to VARCHAR and searching if 'Retrieve Document'
- `userId NOT IN ('master', 'admin')` filtering users other than the users in the list (the actual list is longer than 2 strings around 10 strings)
- 18.7 million rows  in the table

A couple of points to note

- I don't create this table and I can't change it
- I don't have `SHOWPLAN` permission
- I need to use this query in Excel data connections and have the user run it from excel. The user will have only select privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you cannot change the existing table, it may be better to change your strategy.
Instead of running your query and building a new set of results completely every time. Why don't you insert new results into another table (lets call it AccumulatedResults) on a monthly basis.

That way you are only handling the 500K new recs each time. This will be much faster than rebuilding the entire result set every time. The query will look a little like:

```
INSERT INTO AccumulatedResults
(
  MonthYear,
  [COUNT],
  UniqueCustomers,
  UniqueUsers,
)  
SELECT
  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a_timestamp), 0) AS MonthYear,
  COUNT(*) AS [Count],
  COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) AS [Unique Customers],
  COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS [Unique Users]
FROM
  [my_table]
WHERE
  messageType = 'Outbound' AND
  userId NOT IN ('master', 'admin') AND
  CHARINDEX('Retrieve Document', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [message])) > 1

  -- This is a new condition
  AND DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a_timestamp), 0) 
  > (SELECT MAX(MonthYear) FROM AccumulatedResults)

GROUP BY
  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a_timestamp), 0)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the idea of creating a new table. I need to use this query in excel data connections and have the user run it from excel. The user will have only select privileges. hence this might not be the best answer. I will update the the question to reflect this

Comment: With my solution the end user would query "AccumulatedResults" from the excel spreadsheet, which would be almost instantaneous. You would run the above query only once a month only to insert new results as a separate job.

Comment: By separate job, you mean a trigger?

Comment: Either run a script manually once a month, or use a scheduled job in SSIS. There are many ways to run a SQL script periodically. The bottom line is that the user is querying a much smaller table with pre-prepared results which of course is going to much faster. The "AccumulatedResults" table should probably have a primary index on "MonthYear".

Comment: Ok I will try it and then let you know how it goes